# String validation in C

Tags: c, string

I want my variables contains only character in C without anything else like special characters or number and not empty. What is the best solution for this?

I have tried the following code but it is not the best in my opinion:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
char s (20);
do{
printf("Enter your string");
scanf("%s",&s);
}while((strcmp(s,"") ==0))}
```

Comment: Traverse the string char by char and use [`isalpha()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isspace.3.html)

Comment: The string will never be empty. That's not possible with `%s` specifier.

Comment: This doesn't compile as C. It almost does as C++ but `char s (20);` is a single character, not an array, making the whole thing undefined behavior.

Comment: @RetiredNinja hmm... "It **almost** does as C++...." Almost? Weird compiler that is

Comment: Sounds like `getchar` is your best option

Comment: One solution is to write a function which does what you want. That keeps the calling code free from getting bogged down with the details, and makes it easier for you to re-use later in another project.

Comment: @SupportUkraine It's only missing one `;`, that's pretty close. :)

Comment: BiBeoLovesCoding, What should happen if the user types in a non-letter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to loop through your string and check every single character is alphabetic or not, using `isalpha()` function.

The `isalpha()` function returns a non-zero value (true) if the character passed is alphabetic, if not it returns 0 (false).

Don't forget to include the `<ctype.h>` header file.

```
    char str[] = "string";
    size_t length = strlen(str); // get the length of the passed string

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (!isalpha(str[i]))
            return 0; // invalid character
    }
    return 1; // all characters are valid
```

Comment: For safety: `isalpha(str[i])` --> `isalpha((unsigned char)str[i])`. Unfortunately the functions from `ctype.h` expect `int` arguments in the range of `unsigned char`. Also, `int i` should be `size_t i` since `length` is a `size_t` value.

Comment: @adabsurdum Actually you're right, I didn't notice. Thankss!